Is there a more efficient way to find if certain values exist in the DataFrame?
I have a python pandas dataframe with columns "location", "product" and "amount." Example:
data = [['park', 'cookie', 2], ['park', 'muffin', 0], ['park', 'scone', 3], ['mall', 'cookie', 0], ['mall', 'muffin', 0], ['mall', 'scone', 0], ['store', 'cookie', 8]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['location', 'product', 'amount']) 

I want to figure out if all amounts at a certain location is 0. To do this I take two conditions on the dataframe and then check if the dataframe is empty like this:
def location_has_nothing(loc):
    location_condition = df['location'] == loc
    amount_condition = df['amount'] != 0
    df_filtered = df[location_condition][amount_condition]
        return df_filtered.empty

So if loc = park, it would return false and if loc = mall it would be true. I'm new to data frames so I am wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this or if this is how you would do it?
Thank you!

Code
use groupby + all
out = df['amount'].eq(0).groupby(df['location']).all()

out
location
mall      True
park     False
store    False


If you want separate output for each item, indexing it or use get function. Using get function prevents KeyError from occurring on non-existent items.
loc = 'mall'
print(out.get(loc, 'not exist'))


True


Thank you! You panda wizardry is much appreciated

I actually only want to check for a subset of locations. How would you limit df['amount'].eq(0).groupby(df['location']).all() to check only for a subset of locations? Say I only want to check for "park" and "mall"?

@meelszz chk pandas indexing
